# Extending the line drawn above footnotes

Tags: footnotes, rules

By default the line drawn where the footer begins is small in size. How can I make it bigger and make it match with the document text area size?

Comment: At first you should clarify by a [minimal example](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl) how you get that line and where the problems are. Regardless of that, you should consult the manual of the package you use for your footer (and header). It will certainly be helpful.

Comment: Greetings! I've taken the liberty of adjusting the header of your question to better reflect the question's content -- it's about footnotes and footnote rules, not about footers. I've also changed the tag.

Comment: Yes @Mico. It was my mistake

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can modify the `\footnoterule` command:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern-3\p@
  \hrule\@width \textwidth
  \kern2.6\p@}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Test \footnote{test} \lipsum*[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With a [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) class, you may use the `\setfootnoterule[<height>]{<length>}` macro.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\setfootnoterule[2pt]{\textwidth}% default height is 0.4pt

\begin{document}

Some text\footnote{A footnote.}.

\end{document}
```